# Out of the Box - WebService - DB - WebPage/Mobile access

Tags: java, rest, web-services, architecture, frameworks

I would like to install a WebService server in a local machine where i can have a database with a single table that I can use to record/delete/modify  an data object that has a few fields, the WebService will be accessed by a webpage and by a mobile client where I can browse and post the data object (JSON if possible).

I am looking for an out of the box solution for this as I don want to spend much time troubleshooting and configuring a lot of things, I am familiar with Java but any other solution is cool for me.

Any recommendations to achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a project using spring initializer(spring.io) with web,H2 DB(in memory DB) and angular frontend ,Download zip ,unzip it and import it to intellij.